# Formatting text in a table

Tags: tables, tabularx

I cannot format in a fancy way the text inside a table. Basically I don't like the spacing in the first column as shown in the image.

[image]

Someone can help me to format this table in a more readable way?

This is my code:

```
\begin{figure}[ht]
 \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}%
        {
         >{\hsize=1\hsize\small}X
         >{\hsize=1\hsize \small \rule{0pt}{4ex}}X 
         }
   \hline
    AICPA 2014 TS & FERPA \\ 
    BITS Shared Assessments SIG v6.0 & GAPP (Aug 2009)  \\
    COBIT 5.0 & HIPAA / HITECH Act\\
    COPPA & ISO/IEC 27001:2013 \\
    CSA Enterprise Architecture & ISO/IEC 27002:2013 \\
    CSA Guidance V3.0  & ISO/IEC 27017:2015 \\
    ENISA IAF 95/46/EC - European Union Data Protection Directive & ISO/IEC        27018:2015 \\
    FedRAMP Security Controls --low impact level  --   & ITAR \\
    FedRAMP Security Controls --moderate impact level -- & NIST SP800-53 R4 App J \\  
    NZISM  & PCI DSS v3.0\\

   \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Well, if you don't like the spacing in the 1st column why do you specifiy it that way?

Comment: @Christian Hupfer: I think the problem is the interword spacing in some cells of the 1st column

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this better?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}%
\usepackage{tabularx, booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht]
 \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}%
        {
         >{\small\raggedright}X
         >{\small \rule{0pt}{4ex}\raggedright\arraybackslash}X
         }
   \toprule
    AICPA 2014 TS & FERPA \\
    BITS Shared Assessments SIG v6.0 & GAPP (Aug 2009) \\
    COBIT 5.0 & HIPAA / HITECH Act\\
    COPPA & ISO/IEC 27001:2013 \\
    CSA Enterprise Architecture & ISO/IEC 27002:2013 \\
    CSA Guidance V3.0 & ISO/IEC 27017:2015 \\
    ENISA IAF 95/46/EC – European Union Data Protection Directive & ISO/IEC 27018:2015 \\
    FedRAMP Security Controls –\,low impact level\,– & ITAR \\
    FedRAMP Security Controls –\,moderate impact level\,– & NIST SP800-53 R4 App J \\
    NZISM & PCI DSS v3.0\\
   \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The `–` characters aren't being rendered correctly in the screenshot. Replace them with `---`?

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I tried your code and I noticed that I have different spacing between rows (row 7, 8 , 9). This is my screenshot with your code: http://i63.tinypic.com/sfgwf8.png

I don't know why with the same code i have different spacing between rows

Comment: @Mico: I had forgotten to load `[utf8]{inputenc}`, so they weren't displayed, of course. Fixed! Thanks for pointing it.

Comment: I found the problem, it was \renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{ >{\arraybackslash}m{#1}}